# Question regarding definition of 'Markov process' in Shreve book and remark related to it

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

I have a question regarding the definition of 'Markov process' given by Shreeve, book II (continuous models).

It says (see below) this: "Assume that for all $0 \leq s \leq t \leq T$ and for every nonnegative Borel-measurable function $f$, there is another Borel-measurable function $g$ such that $\mathbb E [ f(X(t)) \mid \mathcal F (s) ] = g(X(s)$.

I get very confused from his comments in the Remark below it.
It says there that $f$ is "permitted to depend on $t$" and $g$ depend on $s$.

***I do understand the Definition as stated, but I do not understand the Remark following it.***

What does this mean? Why is this necessary? If we pick some times $s,t$ with $0 \leq s \leq t \leq T$ then these times are fixed--It's unclear to me what a function "depending on $t$" means then.

Can someone clarify this definition? I do not understand what it means.

Together with this, I also do not understand why we can take $g$ to be the same symbol as $f$.

In general, I just don't understand what is meant here. Can someone explain? It would be highly appreciated if someone could give a more precise statement/formulation of what Shreve means here. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: It is the standard definition of a Markov process that you will find everywhere. Perhaps you should step back a bit and figure out on what the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[f(X(t))|{\cal F}(s)]$ genuinely depends. If this is still unclear to you it does not make sense to talk about a Markov process. Hint: which $X_u$ have been used to define ${\cal F}(s)\,?$ Hint II. Doob-Dynkin Lemma.

Comment: You did not read my question properly. I do understand the Definition, which can indeed be found everywhere--the problem is with the Remark following it. You have not given any clarification as to what it means. The problem is with the logical dependencies of the quantifiers. You also haven't given an explanation as to why the same symbols can be used for f and g. All in all, you haven't said anything at all.

Comment: Also, you say the definition can be found "everywhere", and that is true if we consider the definition with Eq. (2.3.29). I'd be very happy though if you could point me to any resource which has a definition involving an equation of the form (2.3.30) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I too find this Remark 2.3.7. a bit hard to follow probably even slightly incorrect,
in the sense that Shreve should have written that "and the function $g$ will depend on
$\color{red}{t}$" (this might be a typo).

- Regardless if $f$ depends on $t$ or not, a way of writing the Markov property is
  $$
  \mathbb E\big[f\big(X_t)\,\big|\,{\cal F}_s\big]=\mathbb E\big[f(X_t)\,\big|\,X_s\big]\,.
  $$
  From the RHS we see that the function $g$ should ***always*** depend on $t\,$ (and $X_s\,$).
- When $f$ depends on $t$ also we use the fact that $(t,X_t)$ is trivially a Markov process (with the same filtration as $X\,$). Then
  $$
  \mathbb E\big[f\big(t,X_t)\,\big|\,{\cal F}_s\big]=\mathbb E\big[f(t,X_t)\,\big|\,X_s\big]\,.
  $$
  The function $g$ on the RHS now depends on $t$  and  $X_s$ again
  but **not** on $s$ because that is not random: $\sigma(s,X_s)=\sigma(X_s)\,.$
- Simple example: Brownian motion (or any other martingale):
  $$
  \mathbb E[t\,W_t\,|\,{\cal F}_s]=\color{red}{t}\,W_s=g(\color{red}t,W_s)\,.
  $$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: What about Eq. (2.3.30) in Shreve? Is it correct? Also, why can we use the same symbol for the functions $f$ and $g$?

Comment: It is obvious that $g$ will depend on $t$. But, why would it be necessary to write this in the notation? There seems no need for it. 

I understand the Definition as stated--but I still don't understand the Remark following it. This discussion about dependencies etc. is quite subtle, and Shreve causes a lot of confusion here. 

One core point of confusion is the use of the *same* symbol for the functions $f$ and $g$: This is (highly) problematic, *as $f$ and $g$ have a completely different place in the expression of the logic* here. That is: we have a $(...) \forall f: \exists g (...)$.

Comment: You say that it might be a typo by Shreve, but I doubt that: Why would he keep repeating that "typo" then? He's very 'consistent' in saying that "g will depend on s". (See e.g. also Eq. (2.3.30).)

Comment: Personally, if I were to use a function $g$ to denote the RHS in the answer I gave I would add all arguments it depends on. In particular $t\,.$ I do therefore not like Shreves's notation. A typo that is repeated is still a typo, and typos happen to the best of us. On top of that: I am not a big fan of reading every remark in the literature as if it was the only authoritative text on the matter. Be patient, read other stuff and don't forget to think it through yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your advice--you make some good points. However, until I reach a certain skill level in some subarea of math (I am a researcher in an entirely different, more abstract in some sense, part), I really do need solid definitions/explanations. So if there is a problem, I really want to find out everything about it until it is 100% clear. I am allergic to ambiguity (in math). Again, thanks!